# Driving on the moon

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag

I think that a car which is applying its max force on Earth stops accelerating (as in, stops increasing in speed) because of air resistance. But on the moon there is none so I think the car would accelerate indefinitely.

The curve of the moon is very slight, but at some great speed would the car ever lift off the ground and fly into space?

Comment: The theoretical max speed would be $$v  = \sqrt{g_{moon} R_{moon}} $$ when you are essentially in orbit on the surface of the moon.

Answer (score 5):

The major friction encountered by a vehicle on the moon will be rolling friction. The surface of the moon is covered in a fine "dust" that is deformed by the pressure of the tires of the vehicle (and more so by boots):

[image]

This means that the wheel is always "rolling up hill" against (weak moon) gravity; that is experienced as rolling friction because work has to be done to move forward. You experience this when driving a car along the beach - you need to be in low gear and fuel consumption shoots up.

Aside from this, if your lunar vehicle was powerful enough to overcome the friction and somehow kept accelerating, the uneven surface of the moon would keep it from maintaining contact with the moon surface - it would spend a lot of time "suspended" with the wheels spinning.

Assume that you made a completely smooth, straight "runway" - overcoming the above objections - you would accelerate until you reached the velocity of the "low" orbit of the moon - in other words, you would lift off when you were driving at the speed at which a satellite would orbit. At that moment your normal force would be zero and wheels no longer work. But you would not reach escape speed by doing that. In fact the orbital velocity is a factor $\sqrt{2}$ smaller than the escape speed. See for example [the second block on this page](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vesc.html)

Comment: ++ Yes. But if your runway took the form of a helical loop which then exited upward, you could do it :)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey a stairway to heaven? Catchy title...

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have a conventional automobile, but with a very very powerful engine- that can continue to produce enough power to accelerate even when it is travelling at a very high velocity and with huge frictional losses and air resistance.

Now that we got the weakness of the engine out of the way, let us assume that there is a perfectly 'smooth' and 'straight' road constructed all the way around the moon. By smooth, I mean smooth as a racetrack and not smooth like a skating rink, ie., the road has only microscopic roughness that produces friction. It does not have any macroscopic bumps, etc.

Having defined the operating conditions (which, I hope, is what the OP asked), let us examine how the car accelerates. The engine exerts a torque on the wheels, which is translated to motion if there is sufficient friction between the wheel and the road. As we all know, the limiting friction that the road can exert on the car, accelerating it depends on the amount of **normal or contact force** between the road and the wheels of the car. If the normal force is large, a large amount of friction is available and the car, if it has a powerful enough engine, can accelerate by a large amount. However, if the normal force becomes zero, there can be no frictional force. The normal force is provided by the **force of gravity** on your car.

Let us make an assumption about our car. Let us assume that it has good aerodynamics for speeding, ie., fast moving air won't cause it to become airborne. When we start to zoom around the moon in our hypothetical car, initially, we will accelerate normally (as normal as you can expect in the moon). Granted, the maximum acceleration will be much lower than the acceleration you can expect on Earth, but still you can accelerate. However, as you keep increasing your speed, something strange happens. You will find that the maximum acceleration you can maintain without skidding on the road keeps reducing. This is because, as you keep increasing your speed, the centrifugal force due to your motion around the moon starts coming into picture, and it acts against the gravitational force, effectively reducing the amount of normal force on the tyres of the car, lowering your acceleration. This will continue, until you slowly reach the orbital speed on the surface of the moon, where the gravitational force is completely balanced by the centrifugal force due to your motion. At this point, your car engine becomes useless (even if it has plenty of spare power), as your car is effectively floating around now. Thus, the orbital speed of the moon is the largest speed that you can achieve when travelling in a conventional automobile, although there are plenty of easier ways to travel at this speed.

---

Answer (score 1):

Nothing with mass can accelerate indefinitely. What it seems you are asking is about coasting. While its true that there is a degree of energy loss from wind resistance, there is also a great deal in the axles of your vehicle. You would decelerate on a flat track more slowly, but you would eventually lose all of your kinetic energy.

To answer your second question, you need to remember that the moon is not a ping pong ball. While it is much smaller than Earth, it still has a sufficient amount of mass that the mass of you or a car is utterly insignificant to it, so you can't just escape with the engine available in your average production car. Look up Newton's Cannon for more on this. While the energy required to escape the gravity well is far less than that on Earth, to achieve the effect of Newton's cannon, you need to be able to reach ~1677 m/s, or 3751 mph. Basically, a naval gun could get the effect, never a car.

Edit: In response to OP's comment, Wind resistance isn't as big a factor in top speed as you might think. You might be able to squeeze 10-20 mph (eyeball math) on the moon, but that's primarily because the car weighs less. There's not much difference in a car's top speed on a Dyno and a drag strip.

Comment: I meant that the car is being accelerated but it reaches a max speed say 140mph because of wind resistance.

Answer (score 0):

On Earth, the major component of friction is engine friction up to about 35 mph. Beyond that it is wind. A car running on an internal combustion engine (carrying a great big air tank) would still have engine friction.

Cars trying to break land speed records on Earth often go to the [Bonneville Salt Flats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonneville_Salt_Flats) because they are flat. At speed, every little bump tends to lift the car off the road. Besides making it hard to control the car, a wheel not in contact with the ground cannot propel the car. A car driven by wheels cannot go faster than 400 mph because the wheels spend too little time on the ground.

I don't have references for these numbers. They are just things I have heard. But the idea is good even if the numbers are off.